# How to change text color of Android's preferences?

Tags: android, text, coding-style, preferences, titlebar

I want to change the look of my Android app's preference screen to white background and dark text color. It seems that I can change background color in the code. Is there a similar way to change text color of preferences in the code?

```
getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
getListView().setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
```

The other way could be setting the activity's theme to light in the app's manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"
```

However, this overrides the application's style, which currently is set to

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Thus, title bar is displayed in the preferences screen. I can try to remove the bar by

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

The app then crashes (`AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content`) when trying to open preferences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Theme.Light.NoTitleBar :)

Comment: Thanks. For anybody else who encounters similar problem: it seems that there are quite a few default themes, though far from well-documented (http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/themes.xml;h=6b3d7407d1c895a3c297e60d5beac98e2d34c271;hb=HEAD).